# Highcharts legend labels go outside canvas

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am having an issue when trying to make long legend labels to fit inside the canvas. Please have a look [`at the fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/542ja/1/)

I can't find any options or fixes for this.

How can I make the long labels to fit inside the plot area? Please advice.

Comment: It seems that your link isn't working. Can you please provide a new one?

Comment: That's weird. It was working yesterday. I've created new one: http://jsfiddle.net/xvpj7frs/ please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set width for legend and for items, to tell Highcharts what is proper width. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/xvpj7frs/3/

```
        legend: {
            width: 300,
            itemStyle: {
                width: '250px'
            }
        },
```

Of course that solution has limitation - legend isn't responsive anymore.

Comment: I can not set width in pixels, I need it to be relative to the container. Which would help if I could set width in percentage, but I don't think it is possible.

Comment: In % it won't work. How about resigning from built-in legend and creating your own?